# Ruby: get a sibling module

Tags: ruby

So far I know to get a child module, one should performs such an operation:

```
module ParentModule
  module Foo
    # to be implemented
    def self.get_bar
      ::ParentModule::Bar
    end
  end

  module Bar
    # to be implemented
  end
end
```

However is there a way to get a sibling module without referencing a parent one? Something like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.get_bar
    ::Bar # doesn't work actually
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried just omitting the `::ParentModule` part? What are you seeing and what have you tried?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The terms "parent" and "child" imply inheritance, but there is no inheritance here.

Comment: Of course I've tried. If I refer to a Bar module from the Foo module
<!-- language: ruby -->
    def self.get_bar
      ::Bar
    end
I get *NameError: uninitialized constant*

Comment: I mean module nesting and refering to a neighbour module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than you thought

```
module ParentModule
  module Foo
    def self.get_bar
      Bar
    end
  end
end
```

The `::` you tried with, it instructs ruby to look this name up in the top-level scope. If you omit it, ruby will first look in the current scope, then its parent, then its parent, and all the way to the top-level.

So, `ParentModule::Foo::Bar` will not be found, but `ParentModule::Bar` will be.

Answer (score 1):

```
mod = ParentModule::Bar
  #=> "ParentModule::"
parent_str = mod.to_s[/.+::/]
  #=> "ParentModule::" 
kids = ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m| m.to_s =~ /^#{parent_str}/ }
  #=> [ParentModule::Bar, ParentModule::Foo]
```

So `mod`'s siblings are:

```
kids - [mod]
  #=> [ParentModule::Foo]
```

Comment: I think you "overengineered" this :)

Comment: @Sergio, I'm not sure it's over-engineered for the question I answered, which, unfortunately, is not the one that was asked. I sought to identify a module's (unknown) "sibling" modules.

Comment: Yes, you answered the wrong question, it seems. But it should work for that question. May I offer what I think to be a simpler solution? http://pastie.org/10658469

Comment: Actually, don't mind my code, it's answer to the same question again :)

Comment: Thanks, @Sergio. I had forgot about `Nesting`.